# angualr2 return observable from subscribe

Tags: angular, observable, angular-promise, angular2-services

Let's take a look at this example. I'm trying to return an observable value
from subscribe, but somehow I get empty value. 
This is scratch of my problem:

```
this.userService.getAll().subscribe((userCollection) => {

        userCollection.data.forEach((user) => {

            let data = {
                id: user.id
                domainName: this.userService.getDomain(user.id).subscribe(
                    (domain) => {
                        console.log(domain.name); // I can see this in console
                        return Observable.of(domain.name);
                    }
                )
            };

            this.array.push(data);
        });
 });
```

template:
   `<div *ngFor="let values of array|async">
    {{ values.id }} 
    {{ values.domainName }} //empty
    </div>`

Can anyone help with this please? Am I doing it in right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `map()` instead of `subscribe()`.

`subscribe` binds a handler and returns a `subscription` object that you can use later to `unsubscribe()`.

```
domainName: this.userService.getDomain(user.id).map(
                (domain) => {
                    console.log(domain.name); // I can see this in console
                    return domain.name;
                }
            )
```

Also, you do not need to return an `Observable`, mapping returns an observable.